# hide images div container if there is no images in the database

Tags: php, html, database

How to hide images in a div container if there are no images in the database? This is what I've tried:

```php
<!-- Featured image -->
<?php if (!empty($productImages)) { ?>
    <img>" alt="" id="featured-image">
<?php } else { ?>
    <img>" alt="" id="featured-image" style="display: block;">
<?php } ?>

<!-- Small images -->
    <div class="small-Card">
    <?php if (!empty($productImages)) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($productImages as $key => $image) { ?>
            <img src="uploads/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="" class="small-Img">
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>

<?php } ?>
```

I want the class="small-Card" to be hidden if there is no data in the database

Answer (score 2):

just try a simble if condition to add style="display: none; or d-none if you're using bootstrap

```
<div class="small-Card" 
   <?php if (empty($productImages)) { echo 'style="display: none;"'; } ?>>
     <?php if (!empty($productImages)) { ?>
         <?php foreach ($productImages as $key => $image) { ?>
             <img src="uploads/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="" class="small-Img">
         <?php } ?>
       <?php } ?>
   </div>
```

if you don't want the div the be even displayed and not just hidden in your project englob the div with the if condition !!

and if you want to remove the class small-Card just put the condition before the class attribute.

and maybe try to make you code more readable and maintainable

```
  $hasImages = !empty($productImages);

  <!-- Featured image -->
  <img src="
      <?= $hasImages ? 
          'uploads/' . $productImages[0] :
          ''; ?>"
  alt="" id="featured-image" style="display: <?= 
  $hasImages ? 'block' : 'none'; ?>;"
  >

  <!-- Small images -->
  <?php if ($hasImages) : ?> // put the if condition where you need it
      <div class="small-Card">
          <?php foreach ($productImages as $key => $image) : ?>
              <img src="uploads/<?= $image; ?>" alt="" class="small-Img">
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks bro, the first code you give me is working for the empty data, but the problem is that the small-Card that contains images don't show all the images , there is 4 images but only 3 are showen, and i didn't have this problem before editing the code. please help me.

Comment: try dumping productImages to be sure that the data exist !